# Centos 6, Plesk 11, EPEL 6 install problems

Tags: linux, centos6, mcrypt, epel, php-mcrypt

I'm having a real headache configuring a new server.  It's a 64bit Linux box with Centos 6 and Plesk 11.  This will be a Magento server, so I need mcrypt installed, which isn't available by default.

I've installed EPEL 6, confirmed here:

```
[root@ds-xxxxxxx ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * epel: mirror.affix.me
 * extras: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * rpmforge: www.mirrorservice.org
 * updates: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
repo id                repo name                                                    status
base                   CentOS-6 - Base                                              6,346
epel                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64               7,070
extras                 CentOS-6 - Extras                                                4
rpmforge               RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                                  4,392
updates                CentOS-6 - Updates                                             165
repolist: 17,977
[root@xxxxxx ~]#
```

But when I run a yum update, it looks like it's trying to load el5 & el6 extensions/modules so causes an issue;

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * epel: mirror.affix.me
 * extras: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * rpmforge: www.mirrorservice.org
 * updates: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.1-2.el6_0.1 will be updated
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.4.1-1.el5 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.0()(64bit) for package: git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package libarchive.x86_64 0:2.8.3-4.el6_2 will be updated
---> Package libarchive.x86_64 0:2.8.4-5.el5 will be an update
---> Package mod_wsgi.x86_64 0:3.2-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package mod_wsgi.x86_64 0:3.2-2.el5 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libpython2.4.so.1.0()(64bit) for package: mod_wsgi-3.2-2.el5.x86_64
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.7.1-2.el6_0.1 will be updated
---> Package perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.7.4.1-1.el5 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-Git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package python-ethtool.x86_64 0:0.6-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package python-ethtool.x86_64 0:0.6-2.el5 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-ethtool-0.6-2.el5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-expat1.x86_64 0:1.95.8-8.el6 will be installed
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.4.1-1.el5 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package mod_wsgi.x86_64 0:3.2-2.el5 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libpython2.4.so.1.0()(64bit) for package: mod_wsgi-3.2-2.el5.x86_64
---> Package openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-17.el6.centos.2 will be installed
---> Package perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.7.4.1-1.el5 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-Git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package python-ethtool.x86_64 0:0.6-2.el5 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.4 for package: python-ethtool-0.6-2.el5.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: perl-Git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: mod_wsgi-3.2-2.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpython2.4.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: python-ethtool-0.6-2.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
           Installed: python-2.6.6-29.el6_2.2.x86_64 (@base)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python26-2.6.8-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
               python(abi) = 2.6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few rebuilds and tweaking I discovered the issue was the order in which I installed things on the server. The issue seems to have been plesk 11 being installed first. So I rebuilt the server, installed the el6 repo first, then mcrypt and yum updates, then installed plesk.

Works like a charm now.

Hope this helps someone else.